# Are these igneous Liesegang rings on a popular Oahu, Hawaii hike?

Tags: geology, petrology, igneous, weathering

I hiked the Lanikai Pillbox trail ([Oahu, HI](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lanikai+Pillbox/@21.3893391,-157.716528,16.75z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x7c0014f892682f7f:0xec50e2c96a16e2b1!2sLanikai+Beach!3b1!8m2!3d21.3925378!4d-157.7151208!3m4!1s0x7c0014f7ab4d2761:0xc586727ccfefbd4a!8m2!3d21.3855953!4d-157.7166534)). I noticed eroded concentric rings in the igneous rock with a hard center. I'm unable to find the geologic cause of these rings. Are they Liesegang rings? There were several instances (~20) I observed on the hike.

[image: Concentric rings in igneous rock in Oahu, HI hike.]

Comment: Maybe try to crash it with a hammer and see what is inside the hard center? By the way, it looks like the model of a cell : )

Comment: It's unlikely to [Liesegang rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liesegang_rings_(geology)), they are colored rings which *usually* occur in sedimentary rocks. They can occur in permeable igneous rocks that have been chemically weathered, where they appear as rings of iron oxide. I don't see any significant color differences in your picture.

Comment: Query: Is the circular rock, at the center of the ringed structure, flat or domed?

Comment: @Fred circular rock is slightly domed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing the setting and judging from the image alone in this trampled environment, I think we're looking at a form of chemical weathering called "[spheroidal weathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroidal_weathering)".

The gist is this (from the linked wiki page):
Penetrating water alters the bed-rock [along cracks or joints](https://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/en/v/geolearning/mountain_building/weathering/weathering2/index.html), causing volume changes between altered and unaltered parts. These differences result in the formation of spheroidal layers that are removed by erosion (or trampling), leaving a central relatively unaltered boulder/pebble.

Liesegang rings are somewhat enigmatic, not sure if the term is applicable here.

Comment: Nice work, @Earthworm. Thank you. Your answer helped me find primary resources confirm that this case is most likely "spheroidal weathering." Source 1: "Trace element mobility during spheroidal weathering of basalts and andesites in Hawaii and Guatemala; Patino et al.; https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chemgeo.2003.01.002; [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0009254103002511#BIB11)

Comment: Yep, I think that's it. But "Tertiary" in a paper from 2003 ? tststs ... :-)